# How do I add a string from c# function into a meta tag (inside quotes)?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, meta-tags

This works

```
<title><%=MyLib.data.GetMetaTitle()%></title>
```

---

This does not

```
<meta name="description" content="<%=MyLib.data.GetMetaDescription()%>" >
```

Returns:

```
<meta name="description" content="&lt;%=MyLib.data.GetMetaDescription()%&gt;" >
```

---

This sort of works

```
<meta name="description" content="\"<%=MyLib.data.GetMetaDescription()%>"\" >
```

Returns:

```
<meta name="description" content="\"Meta Description"\" >
```

---

SO - I can get the c# function to run outside of quotes, but I can't get the data to appear within quotes in the header.

Comment: Try using single quotes. I know that when doing `<%# Eval %>` for example, using double quotes  results in the page throwing an error.

Comment: Side note: please [edit] post with tag for framework you are using - probably ASP.Net (vs. ASP.Net MVC  / Razor)

Comment: Nope... tried that too.  single quotes don't change the behavior.

Comment: There is something missing here.  <meta name="description" content="<%=MyLib.data.GetMetaDescription()%>" > should work fine.  Is this meta tag inside a head tag with runat="server" ?

Comment: The second example you gave ("This does not...") definitely works for me with the ASPX View Engine, even with ASP.NET MVC 4. Something is different about your configuration. Are you really running ASPX, and if so, WebForms or MVC or something else? What version of .NET (CLR+BCL) and ASP.NET  are you running on? Are you running on the Core version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your concern why this happening because it need the formatted string type value, Here is the solution.

```
<meta name="description" content="<%=string.Format("{0}",MyLib.data.GetMetaTitle())%>"/>
```

Hope it will help you out! In case of any issue kindly let me know.

Happy Coding